# Join two DataFrames with no common columns for calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a calculation based on information that I have in two different datasets.  I need all the information for the first dataframe repetead as many times as the information of the second dataframe.

Example:

DataFrame 1:

```
name   price 
 A       1
 B       2
```

DataFrame 2:

```
 currency    value
  Dollar       1
  Euro         2
```

Expected output:

DataFrame merged:

```
name   price   currency    Value
 A       1       Dollar      1
 A       1       Euro        1
 B       2       Dollar      4
 B       2       Euro        4
```

I've been trying something similar like this, with using an apply and a list, and then converting it into a DataFrame, but with no results. Somehow the currs values is always repeated for every name:

```
lst = []
for index, currs in currencies.iterrows():
    lst.append(prices.apply(lambda pmRow: pd.Series({'name':pmRow['prices'], 'curr':currs['currency']}), axis=1))
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why is Value column 1,1,4,4, not 1,2,1,2? If later use `df1.assign(k=1).merge(df2.assign(k=1)).drop('k', 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need `cross join`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1.assign(A=1), df2.assign(A=1), on='A').drop('A', 1)
print (df)
  name  price currency  value
0    A      1   Dollar      1
1    A      1     Euro      2
2    B      2   Dollar      1
3    B      2     Euro      2
```

And then if necessary muliple columns `price` and `value`:

```
df['value'] *= df['price']
print (df)
  name  price currency  value
0    A      1   Dollar      1
1    A      1     Euro      2
2    B      2   Dollar      2
3    B      2     Euro      4
```