# adding a list to a dataframe whilst concating by length fo DF

Tags: python, pandas

Unable to find a solution for this so apologies if this seems simple.

I have a df as follows :

```
ID, Week
5, 1
6, 1
7, 1
```

I have a list of reason codes as follows

```
['Work', 'Holiday', 'Sick', 'Jury']
```

What I'm trying to do is add this to my current dataframe but multiply this by each unique ID

so i would have something like (i'll only use 1 unique ID for brevity).,

```
ID, Week, Reason
5,  1,    'Work'
5,  1,    'Holiday'
5,  1,    'Sick',
5,  1,    'Jury'
```

I have tried all manner of concats, with varying axis's but I'm none-the-wiser how to approach this.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just so i'm clear, you expect `Work`, `Holiday`, `Sick`, `Jury` to be repeated for all `ID`, `Week` combinations?

Comment: Just ID for now but if you could post both solutions that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939)

```
df['Reason']=[l]*len(df)
unnesting(df,['Reason'])
Out[1014]: 
    Reason  ID  Week
0     Work   5     1
0  Holiday   5     1
0     Sick   5     1
0     Jury   5     1
1     Work   6     1
1  Holiday   6     1
1     Sick   6     1
1     Jury   6     1
2     Work   7     1
2  Holiday   7     1
2     Sick   7     1
2     Jury   7     1
```

---

```
# attached self-define function
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')
```

---

Or we do cross join

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'Reason':l}).assign(Week=1))
Out[1020]: 
    ID  Week   Reason
0    5     1     Work
1    5     1  Holiday
2    5     1     Sick
3    5     1     Jury
4    6     1     Work
5    6     1  Holiday
6    6     1     Sick
7    6     1     Jury
8    7     1     Work
9    7     1  Holiday
10   7     1     Sick
11   7     1     Jury
```

Comment: Thanks for this Wen, really like your self-defined function good sir.

Comment: @Datanovice yw :-) happy coding :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools` for this:

```
import itertools
df_new=(pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df.ID,df.Week,reason_codes)),
    columns=df.columns.tolist()+['Reason']).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))
print(df_new)

    ID  Week   Reason
0    5     1     Work
1    5     1  Holiday
2    5     1     Sick
3    5     1     Jury
4    6     1     Work
5    6     1  Holiday
6    6     1     Sick
7    6     1     Jury
8    7     1     Work
9    7     1  Holiday
10   7     1     Sick
11   7     1     Jury
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I did see you comment first but I think Wen's 2nd solution is the most readable and easy to use in a multitude of situations. Thank you for your solution I really need to practice more! If I'm wrong with my assumption please let me know.

Comment: @Datanovice thats perfectly fine. :) no problem. :) Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

let `codes` be the list of reasons

```
codes = ['Work', 'Holiday', 'Sick', 'Jury']
```

Assign the same codes to all the rows of the data frame. The syntax on the RHS just dupliates the list N times, where N is the length of the data frame

```
df['codes'] = [codes] * len(df)
```

Then stack the `codes` column, i.e. change from horizontal to vertical format. In this step it is also necessary to set the `ID` & `Week` columns as indexes & then reset them after the stack operation is done.

```
df.set_index(['ID','Week']).codes.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(['ID', 'Week'])
```

Outputs:

```
   ID  Week        0
0   5     1     Work
1   5     1  Holiday
2   5     1     Sick
3   5     1     Jury
0   6     1     Work
1   6     1  Holiday
2   6     1     Sick
3   6     1     Jury
0   7     1     Work
1   7     1  Holiday
2   7     1     Sick
3   7     1     Jury
```

The only thing left is to assign an appropriate name to the newly created column, and if your code depends on the index value, fix it appropriately. In this version, the index values are carried over from the original dataframe & repeated four times

Comment: Thanks Haleemur, this worked perfectly! I really like the approach with stack, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to create a DataFrame from

```
df_codes = pd.DataFrame({'codes': ['Work', 'Holiday', 'Sick', 'Jury']})
```

After that you just need to do cross join DataFrames without common columns as in this thread [join-two-dataframes-with-no-common-columns-for-calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649474/join-two-dataframes-with-no-common-columns-for-calculations)

base on that thread, after create `df_codes`, you just need this command:

```
df_new = df.assign(a=1).merge(df_codes.assign(a=1)).drop('a', 1)
```

Output:

```
Out[148]:
    ID  Week    codes
0    5     1     Work
1    5     1  Holiday
2    5     1     Sick
3    5     1     Jury
4    6     1     Work
5    6     1  Holiday
6    6     1     Sick
7    6     1     Jury
8    7     1     Work
9    7     1  Holiday
10   7     1     Sick
11   7     1     Jury
```